Hello, I was looking at my Ubuntu 24.04.1 event viewer and I saw an error that I have never seen before
I was looking at my Ubuntu 24.04.1 event viewer and I saw an error that I have never seen before and the message said the following.
i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] ERROR CPU pipe A FIFO underrun

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. What is your question? Please edit your question and add more details. Is this a desktop or a server? Is Ubuntu installed in the cloud? Also include details of your computer's hardware including the CPU and GPU.

see also here

This question is similar to: CPU pipe A FIFO underrun error. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
